# proof of correctness for summation function with a counter

Tags: isabelle, proof-of-correctness

Given the following summation function:

```
function sum :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"sum i N = (if i > N then 0 else i + sum (Suc i) N)"
by pat_completeness auto
termination sum
apply (relation "measure (λ(i,N). N + 1 - i)")
apply auto
done
```

The stop condition is based on the N and i. I normally perform the induction on lists so I do not really know how to prove this function.

Can you please provide a solution and explanation of the next proof?

> lemma sum_general[simp] : "c ≤ n ⟹ 2 * sum c n + (c - 1) * c = n * (n
>   + 1)

Comment: You should first clarify what you mean by ‘correctness theorem’ here. Do you want to relate the function you defined to the standard summation operator in Isabelle-HOL? Do you want to prove a closed form for this sum? Also note that while you *can* do it this way, it is usually nicer to do the recursion downwards rather than upwards as you did.

Comment: @ManuelEberl I come from Coq background, and this function really looked very interesting to me. I did a quick search, and I found this definition on page 4 of https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/functions.pdf.  I come with a general lemma,  lemma sum_general[simp] : "c ≤ n ⟹ 2 * sum c n + (c - 1) * c = n * (n + 1)", but I can't apply well_founded induction on c <= n. Any hint would be great.

Comment: @keep_learning  I will add the lemma to my main question thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to prove something about a recursively-defined function that you defined by the `function` command and where the recursion goes beyond primitive recursion, the best way is typically to use the induction rule that the `function` command gives you:

```
lemma "i ≤ N ⟹ N * Suc N = 2 * sum i N + i * (i - 1)"
proof (induction i N rule: sum.induct)
  case (1 i N)
  show ?case
  proof (cases "i = N")
  case True
  thus ?thesis sorry
next
  case False
  thus ?thesis sorry
qed
```

This gives you access to the induction hypothesis as "1.IH". I also already added the case distinction that you're going to need.

Note that the `function` package registers the defining equation of `sum` (`sum.simps`) as a `simp` rule. This is not a great idea here because it can make the simplifier loop since the equation is not guarded. I usually remove the equation from the simp set and add guarded versions to avoid this:

```
lemmas [simp del] = sum.simps

lemma sum_simps [simp]: "i > N ⟹ sum i N = 0" "i ≤ N ⟹ sum i N = i + sum (Suc i) N"
  by (auto simp: sum.simps)
```